# Extract JPG from MIME response?

Tags: vb6, jpeg, mime, msxml

I'm consuming a remote WebService, but i'm unable to extract the jpg file contained in the `ResponseBody`. I fact, I do save a file, but how can i remove the Mime headers etc, so i can view the image?

Here's my code:

```
Sub GetImg(ByVal strUrl As String, ByVal XmlBody As String)
    Dim objDom As Object
    Dim objXmlHttp As Object
    Dim strRet As String
    Dim aRes() As Byte, fn As Integer


' Create objects to DOMDocument and XMLHTTP
    Set objDom = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set objXmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Load XML
    objDom.async = False
    objDom.loadXML XmlBody

' Open the webservice
    objXmlHttp.Open "POST", strUrl, False

' Create headings
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "image/jpeg"
    objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(XmlBody)

' Send XML command
    objXmlHttp.send objDom.xml

' Get all response text from webservice
    strRet = objXmlHttp.responseText

' Get image
    aRes = objXmlHttp.responseBody
    fn = FreeFile
    Open "a.jpg" For Binary As fn
    Put fn, , aRes
    Close fn

' Close objects
    Set objXmlHttp = Nothing
    Set objDom = Nothing 

End Sub
```

I get the following ResponseText. I seems the content-type is application/binary, maybe this is why I get the image this way??

```
--MIME_boundaryB0R9532143182121
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-ID: <http://www.borland.com/rootpart.xml>
Content-Location: http://www.borland.com/rootpart.xml
Content-Length: 528
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<NS1:Get_TestImageResponse xmlns:NS1="urn:LabLinkIntf-ILabLink">
<return href="cid:1D9766A6-B088-4408-B023-283F7AB6EEB1"/>
</NS1:Get_TestImageResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--MIME_boundaryB0R9532143182121
Content-ID: <1D9766A6-B088-4408-B023-283F7AB6EEB1>
Content-Length: 1035666
Content-Type: application/binary

BM??
```

However, by using an online soap client, I get the attached answer (If I click on the red name I do get the jpg!!!).

[OnLine SOAP Client Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUDAI.jpg)

Hwo do they do it?

Comment: And, please don't start wondering why I use vb6. It's an application already installed to over 500 clients since 2001. And I just need to add this small subroutine.

Comment: What is the content of the header in the response body?

Comment: Why is the Content-Type of your POST image/jpeg, are you submitting an image?  That header specifies the format of the *request* body.  If you are asking the server for image data, you should set the Accept header in your request instead.

Comment: You normally wouldn't be receiving MIME headers in a response… You'd need to figure out what data format this web service is giving you, and parse it.

Comment: You probably need `Accept: image/jpeg` header if you need the binary image returned in jpeg format. Search for `content-type vs accept` for get an explanation.

Comment: Well, you're right about the headers, I made some corrections, but there's no luck... If i binary open the downloaded file and manualy remove the MIME headers, i have my image, but i'm sure there is a less complicated solution.. any other ideas?